# Hash Function for customised unordered_map

Tags: c++

Actually i am trying to write a hash function for unordered_map with key as struct tm defined

in time.h and value as the result of mktime function which takes pointer to tm structure as

arguement.

Can anybody suggest me a suitable hash function as customised std::unordered_map takes

arguement for self written hash function as 'key,value,hash function,compare'

I am a beginner so please suggest me some good ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add all fields of struct_tm and here is your hash. Or xor them or something similar.

Comment: u mean to say that the logic of hash function should be that the sum of all values of tm struct should be different every time .The limit of my unordered_map is 86400 ie total no of seconds in a day so each time the sum will be different.

Comment: Sure you wan't it different as often as possible, as this is what makes hash tables work fast. I'm sorry if I don't understand the problem you have, but have you read through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function?